# Loading large data sets into MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, database, dataset

I'd like to start tinkering with large government data sets—in particular, I want to work with [campaign contribution records](http://transparencydata.com/docs/contributions/) and [lobbying disclosure records](http://transparencydata.com/docs/lobbying/). The Sunlight Foundation and the Center for Responsive Politics offer [cleaned-up versions](http://transparencydata.com/bulk/) of these data sets for download.

I want to load these data sets into MySQL tables, since MySQL is the database management system I'm most familiar with.

I have two questions:

1. What is the best method for loading these large CSV files into MySQL tables?
2. Is there a better method for loading these data sets into a database and running queries? Should I consider a different database platform? I'm open to alternatives, but I don't know where to start. For now, I'm only going to perform local queries, but at some point I'd like to build a public web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, try MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command. It is normally quite fast for this type of data load.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, properly indexed MySQL tables have no problem with 10s of millions of rows. Especially if you are only performing reads after your import.